# Prove that $\gcd(2^{a}+1,2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two odd positive integers. Prove that $\gcd(2^{a}+1,2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1)=1$.

I tried rewriting it to get $\gcd(2^{2k+1}+1,2^{\gcd(2k+1,2n+1)}-1)$, but I didn't see how this helps.

Comment: We are talking about any two positive odd integers here, so $b$ can be anything despite what $a$ is, so $\gcd(a, b)$ can be any divisor of $a$. Since $a$ is odd, this divisor must also be odd. Therefore, we can rephrase the question as: $$\gcd\left(2^{m(2k+1)}+1, 2^{2k+1}-1\right)$$

Comment: Which makes it trivial :)

Comment: @Puzzled417 $\gcd(a, b)$ must be a divisor of $a$, so $a=m\gcd(a,b)$ for some $m \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak How do we continue from there?

Comment: @NobleMushtak m should be odd

Comment: @miracle173 True, but also not relevant to my proof because I prove it for all $m \in \Bbb{N}$ and then you can deduce that it is true for odd $m$ from there. (Proof is in answer below)

Comment: @NobleMushta: maybe not relevant to your answer but relevant to the statement "we can rephrase the question as ..."

Comment: @miracle173 OK, it is relevant to my answer, too, now, because almagest gave me a tip that shortened my answer. EDIT: Wait, now I'm not even using the fact that $a, b$ are odd anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $r=\gcd(a,b)$ and write $a=rs$. Then you are reduced to finding
$$
\gcd(2^{rs}+1,2^r-1)=\gcd(2^{rs}+2^r,2^r-1)
$$
Since $2^r-1$ is odd and $2^{rs}+2^r=2^r(2^{rs-r}+1)$, we have
$$
\gcd(2^{rs}+2^r,2^r-1)=\gcd(2^{r(s-1)}+1,2^r-1)
$$
If $s=1$, we are done. Otherwise we apply the same argument to conclude
$$
\gcd(2^{r(s-1)}+1,2^r-1)=\gcd(2^{r(s-2)}+1,2^r-1)
$$
and go on.

Turn it into a proper proof by induction.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a prime dividing $2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1,$ then $2^{\gcd(a,b)}\equiv1\pmod p.$ Since $\gcd(a,b)\mid a,$ we also have $2^a+1\equiv(2^{gcd(a,b)})^{a/\gcd(a,b)}+1\equiv1+1=2\pmod p.$ Since $2^{\gcd(a,b)}+1$ is odd, $p$ is odd too, thus $p$ does not divide $2^a+1.$ This shows that $\gcd(2^{a}+1,2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1)=1.$

Hope this helps.

Comment: This holds for all $a,b$ and not necessarily odd?

Comment: @Puzzled417 I'm also not using the fact that $a,b$ are odd in my answer anymore.

Comment: Yes, this holds even when $a,b$ are not necessarily odd.

Answer (score 1):

We $\gcd(a, b)$ is a divisor of $a$, so we have $a=m\gcd(a, b)$. Therefore, we can rephrase the question as:
$$\gcd\left(2^{m\gcd(a, b)}+1, 2^{\gcd(a, b)}-1\right)$$

Now, since $1$ is a zero for $x^m-1$, so we know that:
$$(x-1) \mid (x^m-1)$$
Substitute $x=2^{\gcd(a, b)}$:
$$(2^{\gcd(a, b)}-1) \mid (2^{m\gcd(a, b)}-1)$$

Subtract the latter part of this statement from the former part of the $\gcd$:
$$\gcd(2, 2^{\gcd(a, b)})$$
The latter part is clearly odd, so the $\gcd$ is $1$.

Comment: $2^{2k+1}-1$ is a factor of $2^{m(2k+1)}-1$. So if $p$ divides $\gcd(2^{m(2k+1)}+1,2^{2k+1}-1)$ it must also divide 2.

Comment: @almagest I've added your top to the beginning of my answer.

Comment: @almagest Note that it becomes more intuitive *arithmetically* by using congruences - see my answer. This eliminates *relations* (divisibility) by translating into equivalent arithmetic *operations* (generally we have better intuition on operations than relations).

Answer (score 1):

Any divisor of $2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$ is a divisor of $2^a-1$  since $a$ is a multiple of $\gcd(a,b)$ by definition.

Hence $\;\gcd(2^a+1, 2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1)=\gcd(2^a+1, 2^a-1) =1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ \ d\, =\, (\color{#0a0}{2^A+\ 1},\,\ \ \color{#c00}{2^C\:-\:1}).\, $ $\ A\, =\, C\,N\,\ $ by $\,\ C = (A,B)\mid A,\ $   so

${\rm mod}\ d\!:\: \color{#0a0}{{-}1\equiv}{\color{#0a0}{ 2^A}\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{2^C})^N}\!\equiv\! \color{#c00}{1}^N\!\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\:d\mid 2\:\Rightarrow\: d=1\:$ by $\,d\,$ odd.

Comment: Yes, I just think the result is completely obvious once you grasp the idea of comparing $2^a-1$ and $2^c-1$. But that leap cannot be obvious to everyone or the OP would not have written the question!

Comment: @almagest It's not clear what you mean by "compare". But the above proof is a congruence analog of the other divisibility proofs, and the congruence language makes it more obvious, i.e. you need only recognize that $\,2^{CN}\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{2^C})^N\,$ vs. $\,2^C-1\mid 2^{CN}-1.\,$  The former is obvious even if one does not know the latter. This is but one simple example of how congruences simplify divisibility relations.